# Could you use $|0\rangle$ as excited state and $|1\rangle$ as ground state in transmon?

Tags: superconducting-quantum-computing, transmon

Why is the $|0\rangle$ state usually taken to be the ground state of a transmon qubit, and the $|1\rangle$ state the first excited state? Could you reverse this, and if so how would it affect the qubit's response to noise and 2-qubit gates?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Considering a spin-1/2 qubit, which is the ground state, |0⟩ or |1⟩?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32881/considering-a-spin-1-2-qubit-which-is-the-ground-state-0-or-1)

Comment: This question about transmons, not about spin-1/2 particles, so I disagree with the dupe suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

It would not make any difference whatsoever, as they are simply labels. "Red" and "blue" are equally valid names to give to qubits, albeit clunky ones.

A rose by any other name would smell just as sweet...